# Magento url in backend front: why it contains a pair of key and value

Tags: magento

I try to install Magento,

After that I go to backend front, I see on the url, for example

> index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/54e7a64f35d5956113e5d7efa3a64522/

Why does Magento developer added a pair of key and value(54e7a64f35d5956113e5d7efa3a64522)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is there for security reasons - to be exact, to prevent csrf attacks.

Comment: Configurable in System > Configuration > Admin.